# Angular2/Webpack with Elasticsearch: CORS issue

Tags: elasticsearch, angular, cors, webpack

I have an Angular2 project setup with Webpack. I'm also trying to introduce Elasticsearch into the mix, but I keep getting CORS issues with ES (on port 9200 with the app being served on 8080).

I know this is a common issue with Webpack as I've seen immense Github issue-posts related to it. Furthermore, I know I can simply download a Chrome plugin to disable/enable cross-origin sharing, but I don't want to do this. I'd much rather put the configuration in my JS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The option `http.cors` in `elasticsearch.yml` configuration is the one you want to change.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Answer (score 0):

add below settings in elastic yml

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

and then restart the service